# Django adding new model to a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a forum like dialog where every topic has a ManyToManyField that links to its posts. Here I am trying to create a new topic, meaning a new topic model is created and so is its first post:

```
# views.py
topic_form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
post_form = NewPostForm(request.POST)

if topic_form.is_valid() and post_form.is_valid():
    topic_form = topic_form.save(commit=False)
    post_form = topic_post_form.save(commit=False)

    post_form.posted_by = request.user

    post = post_form.save()
    topic_form.posts.add(post)
    topic = topic_form.save()
```

However I am having trouble finding the correct way to save both forms and add the post to the topic.

Comment: You need to use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) which take care of this linking and saving for you.

Comment: Can you give an example? I do not understand the concept from the documentation or why what I am doing in inefficient.